# How to use Sequential Each Occurrence in JMeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-4.0

I have a body data for a request where I need to pass values from CSV, but for every iteration I need to pass 2 values from file because it is having 2 occurrences of same variable

Bodydata

[image: 1]

How can we pass 2 values for every run in JMeter.

I need sequential each occurrence scenario in JMeter

Data:

claim1
claim2
claim3
claim4

For First run I need to use claim1 and claim2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), you will have to switch to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) where you have more control regarding when to proceed to the next line.

Amend your body to look like

```
{
  "Claims" : [
    {
      "Type": "${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}"
    },
    {
      "Type": "${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}"
    }
  ]
}
```

and you should get what you want.

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)